# Require a script to make a copy of all files in a folder and rename the copies to text files

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I'm looking to run a batch file in a specific folder and copy all files in that directory and rename those copies including it's extension to .txt

I.e, if there are files called `fhnbye.zip` and `212obtr.xls` I want it to make copies of it and rename it to `fhnbye.zip.txt` and `212obtr.xls.txt`

Is that possible?

Comment: why do you want to append the `.txt` extension in every file.

Comment: Hi Shivan, in a sense it's stupid really but in our current environment there's no other way. One of our file servers is running out of space and we need to delete some files. We want to replace all of those files with text files with comments in of when the file was deleted with the last full backup date, so that when the user's go back someday and look for specific files then at least the name of the files are there and they can advise us of which date to restore it from. It's a requirement from management unfortunately.

Comment: Would you want to create empty txt files?  That's just as easy and would be super fast, and take no extra server HDD space.

Comment: I think the thing that would help the most would be to make a copy of all files under a certain folder structure (including files in sub-folders) with .txt and enter specific comments in those txt files. Then after running the script I can just remove all non-txt files? I guess one would start by doing a dir listing...would doing something like this be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a plain batch task:

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\data\folder"
echo creating "%%a.txt"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d ') do copy /y "%%a" "%%a.txt" >nul
popd
```

Comment: This code works well thanks foxidrive, only problem is, it makes the replacing text file the same size as the original file size. Is there a way of replacing the contents of the replacing text file with my own comments to reduce the size?

Comment: Specify the task including the comments and it should be doable.  This question has been answered and an answer should be accepted - to change the question on stack overflow you should really open a new question, as each question and answer should stand on it's own.

Comment: I understand foxidrive, pls see new question posted:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245013/require-a-script-to-make-a-text-file-copy-of-a-file-incl-its-extension-and-repl

Comment: Thanks - please accept an answer by clicking the grey tick, if it solved the question.

Answer (score 0):

OK, not to complicated, but there are some things you need to fill out before you can run this batch file (make sure its run in the same directory):

```
@echo off
set dir="C:\users\...[path to copy target (that is NEW location)]"
copy *.* %dir%\*.txt
```

And **DONE**!

Note, it will ask you for permission to overwrite files, if you have more then one file with the same name.

### Edit 1

This code uses `forfiles` and will only work on windows 7 if you have windows tool installed (most computers will)

```
@echo off
set dir="C:\users\...[path to copy target (that is NEW location)]"
forfiles /c "cmd /c (copy @file %dir%\@file.txt)"
```

It should work fine.

Mona

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know. Appreciate the prompt response thank you Mona!

Comment: Hi Mona, it works, but...is there a way of making a copy of those files to include their extensions, i.e to make abc.xls = abc.xls.txt

Comment: @Tiaan Check in a few min, I'll edit the answer (Note it might only work in windows 7)

Comment: @Tiaan If your computer doesnt have `forfiles`, there is a slightly longer way to do it without relying on it.

Comment: It works like a charm!! I tested it on my Win 7 machine, but need to action it on a Server 2008 R2 box, should still work right?

Comment: @Tiaan I think so, you can install `forfiles` on it if you want (it's very useful for single command batch jobs), otherwise use foxidrive's soloution.

Comment: Hi Mona, you helped me out with this script a while back:

Comment: @echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d ') do (
   echo creating "%%a.txt"
   >"%%a.txt" echo This file has been removed to free space on the E drive.
   rem to delete all the original files you can un-comment the following line by removing the rem
   rem del "%%a"
)
popd

Comment: Is there a way to edit this script so that it applies to all files within subfolders as well?

Comment: @Tiaan Easy, simply add `/s` to `forfiles` as: `forfiles /s`. If you found this useful, please make my answer correct.