# Require a script to make a text file copy of a file incl it's extension and replace the contents of that text file with comments of my own

Tags: batch-file

Thanks to the amazing help of StackOverflow members I have a script that I can run in a folder that makes a copy of all files including their extensions, ex:

Example.xls (124KB) now has a copy Example.xls.txt (124KB)

Problem is, the copy it makes is the same size, and some of the files in our folders are up to 100MB. I want to replace the info in that text file with: "This file has been deleted by John Doe to clear up space on the J drive due to drive running out of space. A backup copy of October 2013 can be retrieved".

That file would then be 1KB and would be available should the Tax deparment user's for instance browse through that drive in future looking for certain files.

So to recap, i would run the below script, but instead of it making the file size the same it should replace the contents of that text file copy with my own comments:

---

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\data\folder"
echo creating "%%a.txt"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d ') do copy /y "%%a" "%%a.txt" >nul
popd
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help - test it on a sample directory:

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\data\folder"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d ') do (
   echo creating "%%a.txt"
   >"%%a.txt" echo This file has been deleted by John Doe to clear up space on the J drive due to drive running out of space. A backup copy of October 2013 can be retrieved
   rem to delete all the original files you can un-comment the following line by removing the rem
   rem del "%%a"
)
popd
```

Comment: foxidrive, you're a legend!! It works perfect and this is going to save me days worth of work. Really appreciate it thank you!!!